# Force a Sharepoint page into content="IE=edge"

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using Sharepoint 2010 where I created a simple webpart page. It's using `http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=10; IE=8"` by default. Problem with that is that Bootstrap 3 doesn't support IE10 or IE8 in compatility modes and respondsjs doesn't work either.

Here is what's documented in the Bootstrap documentation page:

> Bootstrap is not supported in the old Internet Explorer compatibility
>   modes. To be sure you're using the latest rendering mode for IE,
>   consider including the appropriate  tag in your pages:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
> ```

Problem with this is that I dont have access to the Sharepoint master page so I can't change this value. I tried adding it in the header of my page but since the master page loads it first it just simply ignores it.

After many hours spent scavenging the net I found a few articles concerning this issue:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667557/Programatically-Change-Page-Headers-Title-Styleshe

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7cef975b-a409-48cd-8da9-c5660fa55f11/override-master-page-meta-tags-from-child-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlmeta_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

These articles talk alot about adding/modifying the Page_load() or inputting this script somewhere and it should do the trick. I tried adding this to the top of my page, in the header of my page, under the header of my page, in a content editor webpart, and nothing works. I may be be missing the point of all of this but I am stumped. Since I dont have access to Sharepoint Designer either it makes things a bit trickier for me.

Would anyone have any ideas of what i could do from here?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
    meta.Content = "IE=edge";
    HtmlHead head = Page.Header;
    head.Controls.Add(meta);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have access to change the master page? You don't need SharePoint Designer for that... you can do it in Notepad. Also, are you sure you want to make the page run in Edge mode? You'll be breaking a lot of SharePoint out-of-the-box functionality that specifically requires the IE8 emulation of compatibility mode.

Comment: Yes unfortunately the master pages are locked down to IT deps only for obvious reasons. I can only create pages using templates created by the IT dep. I only need to active edge on one page that is running my app and  wouldnt need the Sharepoint OOB features. What I ended doing is removing the @meda queries in my bootstrap css. The page wont be access via mobile eitherway so for now it's all I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
    meta.Content = "IE=edge";
    HtmlHead head = Page.Header;

    head.Controls.AddAt(0, meta);
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Thriggle stated that he had already tried this 'solution' and that he does not have access to the master pages.  I've attempted this same code locally while editing code for a web part as was asked, but it does not work.  Since Thriggle only has access to the web part he is changing, this will only add the tag in that web part and not affecting the layout.  Since IE only uses the first ua compatible node this won't work.